# How i can increase the Storage Limit for my office 365 site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, storage

I am working on an office 365 site collection, and when  i access my site collections i find that all the site collections have a storage limit  = 1 GB , although we have total storage of 1.07 TB as follow:-

[image]

so my question is how i can increase the Storage Limit to be > 1GB?? and is this related to the Server Resource Quota ??
Hint out customer have the Office 365 Business Essentials license.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Manage site collection storage limits you should be `Global Admin` or `SharePoint Admin`.

**Steps**

- Sign in to Office 365 as a global admin or SharePoint admin.
- Open the Office 365 admin center.
- In the left pane, choose Admin centers > SharePoint > Select Settings.
- In Site Collection Storage Management, select Manual > Click OK.
- Go back to Admin centers > SharePoint > On the Site Collections tab choose your site collections from the list > Select Storage Quota.

[image]

- In Limit storage quota, enter the maximum number of gigabytes (GB) to be allocated to the site collection.

[image]

Ref: [Manage site collection storage limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-collection-storage-limits-77389c2c-8e7e-4b16-ab97-1c7103784b08)

Comment: ok thanks for the info.. so what is the relation in this case between the Storage Limit which is set by default to 1GB and Server Resource Quota which is set by defualt to 300?? is there any relation ?

Comment: Storage limit is for data storage.  Server quota has to do with resources consumed by sandbox solutions.

Comment: @GregW sandbox solutions in office 365 ?? is this possible ?

Comment: Yes.  Only declarative ones though.  None that have code as well.

Comment: @GregW so at the end storage limit which is set by defualt to 1GB and the server quota which is set by defualt to 300 ,, can be increased in the future according to our business needs is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct!, by the way, I would like to thank @GregW for his valuable replies :)